# Nativescript where is the folder documents

Tags: android, filesystems, nativescript

I am developing with Nativescript and I need to write and read some files.
I managed to write (I had no errors) but I did not read what I wrote (from an example found on GitHub); also the path of knownFolders.documents() does not correspond to any path on my Android.
Where I can find a documentation?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nativescript's file system. More info on that [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/file-system)

```js
const documents: Folder = <Folder>knownFolders.documents();
const folder: Folder = <Folder>documents.getFolder(vm.get("folderName") || "testFolder");
const file: File = <File>folder.getFile(`${(vm.get("fileName") || "testFile")}` + `.txt`);

file.writeText(vm.get("fileTextContent") || "some random content")
    .then(() => {
        file.readText()
            .then((res) => {
                vm.set("successMessage", `Successfully saved in${file.path}`);
                vm.set("writtenContent", res);
                vm.set("isItemVisible", true);
            });
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Juan, I know this, the problem is on my Android i.e. I am not able to see the path (with a file explorer like X-plore) :path: /data/user/0/org.nativescript.cascinavaraita/files/listino.csv

Comment: I believe that path `/data/user/0/` is internal storage which is not accessible except by the operating system or apps. Writing to external storage might be better if you want to read the file from an external source (outside the app)